# Hide a div inside a hidden div?

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

I have form that will hide or show sections based upon the form input.

For example, a user selects widget type in a step 1 div.

Step 2 is currently hidden with display:none, but I want to set subdiv_detail in step 2 to display:none ahead of time.  When step 2 is shown, subdiv_detail is hidden.

I think that because my outer div is hidden, I cannot call jquery's hide() on the inner div.

Any help appreciated.  Thanks.

--- UPDATE  ---

I figured out what the problem was.  I had an animation running on hide that I forgot to change.

```
$('.subdiv_detail').hide(500);
```

Must be:

```
$('.subdiv_detail').hide();
```

Comment: Why can't the subdiv_detail have style="display:none" when it is rendered?

Comment: Because if a different option is selected in step 1, it should be visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.hide` & `.css` both work fine.

```
 $('.subdiv_detail').css('display', 'none');
 $('.subdiv_detail').hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s5cge/4/

Comment: Something else must be changing the visibility of my element.  Great example.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work alright for me. Reference this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qN6k5/1/

Answer (score 1):

Hide the inner div through css.

```
.subdiv_detail, #subdiv_detail{//Use the right selector based on your markup.
     display:none;
}
```

Through jQuery if you call `hide()` method it will do the same thing.

```
$('#subdiv_detail').hide();
```